# HList as parameter of method with simplified type signature

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

Suppose I have container-marker

```
case class TypedString[T](value: String)
```

where `value` represents some id for particular type `T`.

I have two classes

```
case class User(id: String)
case class Event(id: String)
```

And I have a function which does some stuff:

```
def func[L <: HList](l: L)(...) {...}
```

So I can use it like

```
func[TypedString[User] :: TypedString[Event] :: HNil](
    TypedString[User]("user id") :: TypedString[Event]("event id") :: HNil
)
```

(it's important for me to keep type signature explicitly)

The question is: how to change or extends func to have shorter type signature (keeping only marker types) like:

```
func[User :: Event :: HNil](
    TypedString[User]("user id") :: TypedString[Event]("event id") :: HNil
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapped` type class gives you the relation of one HList `L` and another HList where the elements of `L` are wrapped in a type constructor.

Because you have now two types, the type `L` you want to specify and another type (the elements of `L` wrapped in `TypedString`), we need to use the same trick we used in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38053758/5020846) (then because we didn't want to supply all the arguments at once, now because we only want to specify the first type).

```
import shapeless._
import ops.hlist.Mapped

def func[L <: HList] = new PartFunc[L]

class PartFunc[L <: HList] {
  def apply[M <: HList](m: M)(implicit mapped: Mapped.Aux[L, TypedString, M]): M = m
}
```

Now you can use `func` as you wanted :

```
func[User :: Event :: HNil](
    TypedString[User]("user id") :: TypedString[Event]("event id") :: HNil
)
// TypedString[User] :: TypedString[Event] :: HNil =
//     TypedString(user id) :: TypedString(event id) :: HNil
```